# What's wrong mocking this fetch request in React app?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, fetch, react-testing-library

I am trying to mock a fetch request in a create-react-app project and after spending some time I think this would work, but it keeps throwing 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined'. I cannot figure out why.
Here is the code:

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3005');
        const data = await res.json(); // {value: 'Some text}
        setWord(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <>Loading...</>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>{word.value}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.test.js

```
import { render, screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

global.fetch = jest.fn(() =>
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve({ value: 'text' }),
  })
);

describe('App', () => {
  test('loads the word on mount', async () => {
    await act(async () => render(<App />));
    expect(screen.getByText(/text/)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Comment: do this `console.log(await fetch('http://localhost:3005')` and tell what you are getting?

Comment: Can't reproduce it.

Comment: Use Wirespec to generate your response at a custom endpoint. It's free. https://wirespec.dev

Comment: @Sakshi I get 'undefined'. I am not being able to mock the resolved value of fetch.

Answer (score 0):

There are two render functions that you can use when running tests for React - one from react-dom, and one from react testing library. create-react-app comes with a premade test that uses the render from react testing library, but their testing recipes (which it looks like you're following, here) actually imports render from react-dom. The two render functions don't work the same way, and you're using the react testing library one with syntax designed for the react-dom one. Switch over to importing render from react-dom instead, like this:

```
import { screen, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
```

and it should work.

I found this out by running into a similar issue as you while going through the React testing docs to write tests for my app made with create-react-app.